# Map string array to my array type Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have enum of statuses

Here is it

```
 export enum InvoiceStatus {
    Created = 1,
    Pending = 2,
    Approved = 3,
    Rejected = 4,
    Paid = 5,
    Deleted = 6,
    PreparingPayment = 7
}
```

I need to map it to SelectItem type array

```
    export interface SelectItem {
    label?: string;
    value: any;
    styleClass?: string;
    icon?: string;
    title?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
}
```

I need to map it to label and value

So the label will be the name of enum and value- is enum value.

How I can do this?

Comment: Surely you don't want to remap the key? Can't you just give the interface field 'label' a type of InvoiceStatus `label?: InvoiceStatus` then access the Enum key/value as and when you need it?

Comment: I need to have `1` in value and `Created` in the label for example. But the type of array must be `SelectItem` @Alex

Comment: Surely this means when accessing your interface you'll have no idea what your keys are, as they will be different depending on what your enum status was?

Comment: the enum will be the same everytime@Alex

Comment: Going by what you're asking for, if you instantiate an object using the interface InvoiceStatus, how are you going to access the status if your key can be any of your seven enum values? If you do `selectItem: SelectItem` and then `const status = selectItem.Created` you will either get 1 (if the status is created) or undefined if it's any other status. If you jsut make a key called 'status' be of type InvoiceStatus you could just do `const status = invoiceStatus.status;`

Comment: Don't understand the problem. I have enum defined, so it will be accessible. I need to map enum to SelectItem array, and then use it in the dropdown. @Alex

Comment: Then just give your interface a key of 'status' with a value of 'InvoiceStatus'. `status: InvoiceStatus`. There is no point trying to map a specific enum value into an interface as a key-value pair as you will essentially be making an instance of your interface for each value in your enum.

Comment: I cant give interface smth. It's library interface. So I need to map it @Alex

Comment: This seems like a simple `map` exercise, something that has been asked and answered thousands of times on Stack Overflow alone. Have you done any research or attempted to solve the issue yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
const StringIsNumber = value => isNaN(Number(value)) === false;

// Turn enum into array
function ToArray(enumme) {
    return Object.keys(enumme)
        .filter(StringIsNumber)
        .map(key =>  ( {'label': enumme[key], 'value': key}));
}
let invoiceStatus:any=InvoiceStatus;

let selectItems:SelectItem[]

selectItems=ToArray(invoiceStatus)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 arrayObjects: SelectItem[] =[];
      
for (const [propertyKey, propertyValue] of Object.entries(InvoiceStatus)) {  
      if (!Number.isNaN(Number(propertyKey))) {  
        continue;  
    }  
    arrayObjects.push({ value: propertyValue, label: propertyKey });  
}  
  
console.log(arrayObjects);
```